# Why Player1 and Player2 varibles are not incremented?

Tags: c, windows

Im making a Rock/Paper/Scissors game and in that i have created two variables which display the scores but they are not getting incremeneted....

Basically They are the variables which get incremented according to which player wins.
Just like Rock wins against paper and scissors so whichever player choose rock will win so i created a variable for player 1 which will be incremented when the player 1 will win.

Same goes with the player 2 but turns out they are not getting incremented....

Code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Globally declared variables here
int n;
int Pl1choice, Pl2choice;
int Player1 = 0, Player2 = 0;
// Declarations of the functions here

void generatearandomnumber(void);
void Player1choicedisp(void);
int gamelogic(int Pl1choice, int Pl2choice);
void pl1choices(int Pl1choice);
void pl2choices(int Pl2choice);
int main()
{
    printf("Hey! You are the player no.1 and Computer is Player no.2\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        Player1choicedisp();
        scanf("%d", &Pl1choice);
        generatearandomnumber();
        pl1choices(Pl1choice);
        pl2choices(Pl2choice);
        // For invalid number inputs.
        if (Pl1choice == 0 || Pl1choice == 1 || Pl1choice == 2)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You entered an invalid number so you have to restart the game.\n");
            break;
        }

        gamelogic(Pl1choice, Pl2choice);
    }
    if(Player1 > Player2)
    {
        printf("Winner is Player1\n");
    }
    else if(Player1 == Player2)
    {
        printf("Its a tie\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Winner is Player2\n");
    }
    printf("Scores :-\n");
    printf("Player1 = %d\n", Player1);
    printf("Player2 = %d\n", Player2);
    return 0;
}

// For generating Rock/Paper/Scissors.
void generatearandomnumber(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    Pl2choice = rand() % 3;
}

// For Player1 to enter his choice.
void Player1choicedisp(void)
{
    printf("Enter your choice for the Rock/Paper/scissors\n");
    printf("Enter 0 for ROCK\n");
    printf("Enter 1 for PAPER\n");
    printf("Enter 2 for SCISSORS\n");
}

// Main logic for the game.
int gamelogic(int Pl1choice, int Pl2choice)
{
    if (Pl2choice == 0 && Pl1choice == 1 || Pl1choice == 2)
    {
       Player2++;
       return Player2;
    }
    if (Pl1choice == 0 && Pl2choice == 1 || Pl2choice == 2)
    {
       Player1++;
       return Player1;
    }
    if (Pl2choice == 1 && Pl1choice == 2)
    {
       Player1++;
       return Player1;
    }
    if (Pl2choice == 2 && Pl1choice == 1)
    {
       Player2++;
       return Player2;
    }
}

//For displaying what both of them have chosen.
void pl1choices(int Pl1choice)
{
    switch(Pl1choice)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            printf("Player 1 chose ROCK\n");
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            printf("Player 1 chose PAPER\n");
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            printf("Player 1 chose SCISSORS\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}


void pl2choices(int Pl2choice)
{
    switch(Pl2choice)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            printf("Player 2 chose ROCK\n");
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            printf("Player 2 chose PAPER\n");
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            printf("Player 2 chose SCISSORS\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried declaring them locally and globally as well but turns out they hold 0 as their value till the end of the program..

---

Comment: Don't spam tags. This doesn't look like a C++11 question.

Comment: Some unrelated notes: a) `srand(time(NULL));` You should only call `srand` once at program start, not everytime you need a new number. b) `int gamelogic(int Pl1choice, int Pl2choice);` You have no idea whether `player1` or `player2` was returned. Also you don't use the return value at all. Why don't you make it a `void` function? c) What happens if both player select same choice? d) `if (Pl2choice == 0 && Pl1choice == 1 || Pl1choice == 2)` It would be useful to add brackets to make this more readable.

Comment: `gamelogic()` is not reachable. You either jump over it with the `continue` or `break` out of the loop before.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is never reaching the gamelogic function because of the continue in your loop:

```
if (Pl1choice == 0 || Pl1choice == 1 || Pl1choice == 2)
        {
            continue;
        }
```

A continue causes execution to return to the start of the loop. It doesn't mean continue on from here.

Player1 and Player2 are incremented in the gamelogic function, but it is never called, because Pl1choice must be either 0, 1, or 2, otherwise you have a break.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in you code:

1. `gamelogic` can't be called because it's at the end of a `for` loop always preceded by `break` or `continue`, you should written:

   ```
   if (Pl1choice == 0 || Pl1choice == 1 || Pl1choice == 2)
   {
       gamelogic(Pl1choice, Pl2choice);
   }
   else
   {
       printf("You entered an invalid number so you have to restart the game.\n");
       break;
   }
   ```
2. The code of `gamelogic` is strange (but in your question, you say that rocks always wins, so I may be wrong here):

   If player 2 choose rock, he win agains paper and scissor, same for player 1.

   You have 9 cases to deal with, from player 1 point of view, 3 ties, 3 loss, 3 wins. Pseudo code to do that could look like:

   ```
   gamelogic() {
       if player_1_choice == player_2_choice
           tie (do nothing)
           return
       if ((player_1_choice == rock) and (player_2_choice == paper) or
           (player_1_choice == paper) and (player_2_choice == scissor) or
           (player_1_choice == scissor) and (player_2_choice == rock))
           player_1 loses
           update player 2 score
           return 
       else
           all tie and win cases have been tested, so player 1 wins
           update player 1 score
           return 

   }
   ```

---

Bonus problem:

You don't use `scanf` correctly. If player1 choose a first valid choice and after enter garbage, the first valid choice will be kept for secand and third rounds.

You should at least read what `scanf` returned to see if an error happened.

If -in your case- `scanf` returned `1`, that means that it succeeded reading one integer.

See [beginners-guide-away-from-scanf](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) to learm more about `scanf`.

---

Moreover, you should

- avoid to have global and local variables with the same name: it's confusing
- call `srand` only once at the program beginning and not each time you call `rand`
- use `#define` or better `enum` to work with names like `rock`, `scissors` and `paper` instead of `0`, `1` and `2`
- `gamelogic` returns a integer, but it's not used (you don't read it) and it's value is not really usable. Consider make it returning nothing (`void`)